How to get rid of 'undefined' warnings due to abnormal file importing
I'm coding a project for the Picotron (an advanced version of Pico-8) in the Lua language in VSCode. I have imported my files properly using 'include ' and the code works when I run it. My problem is that VSCode doesn't recognize the imports, and thus gives me an 'undefined' warning for every variable and function declared outside of the current file. I have the 'pico8-ls' extension active. Under every non-local variable there is a warning of:
undefined variable:  PICO-8 LS
with a yellow curled line underneath.
I have two possible solutions in mind, but neither one have I been able to accomplish:

Force the import scope to be the whole project


search for definitions of variables and functions from the entire project folder, as oppose to only looking for it from current file only


Disable the warning


I want to disable the entire warning, not only make the curled lines invisible as many tutorials suggest.

Does someone have an idea of how this could be solved?
Thank you!
I made the curled lines invisible, but I'm not satisfied as the problem messages are still there.
